# How to modify grid-template-areas with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to modify `grid-template-areas` with javascript. I found a property in the css properties list (`elem.style`) in the DOM called: `gridTemplateAreas`. But I seem to be unable to change it with javascript.

How do i modify the `grid-template-areas`-property with javascript?

Here is the code I tried:

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
 let elem= document.getElementById("grid");
 elem.style.gridTemplateAreas = 
   "z z z"
    "a b c"
    "d e f"
   console.log("The grid-template area should have been redefined now. The blue block should have move to the top row.");
});
```

```css
#grid{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:  "x x x"
                        "y y z"
                        "y y z";
}
#div1{
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: z;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click to activate the code</h3>
<div id="grid">
<div id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

PS: I am using Google Chrome a.t.m.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your `elem.style.gridTemplateAreas = 
    "z z z"
    "a b c"
    "d e f"`

Is not a valid statement or it does not do what you want to do.
You want to assign the value `"z z z" "a b c" "d e f"`. Therefore, you need to surround it by quotes like this: `elem.style.gridTemplateAreas = '"z z z" "a b c" "d e f"';`

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(){
 let elem= document.getElementById("grid");
 elem.style.gridTemplateAreas = '"z z z" "a b c" "d e f"';

   console.log("The grid-template area should have been redefined now. The blue block should have move to the top row.");
});
```

```css
#grid{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:  "x x x"
                        "y y z"
                        "y y z";
}
#div1{
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: z;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click to activate the code</h3>
<div id="grid">
<div id="div1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

just change to `elem.style.gridTemplateAreas ='"z z z" "a b c" "d e f"';`

Answer (score 3):

**with styled-components**

```
const Grid = styled.div`
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: ${(props) => props.areas 
  ? props.areas.reduce((acc, str) => (acc += `${"'" + str + "'" + "\n"}`), ``) + ";" 
  : "none"};
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
`

const StyledGrid = () => (
  <Grid areas={["z z z", "a b c", "d e f"]} >
)
```