# CSS grid : incorrect positioning

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I tried to use CSS grid to position elements.
I expect something like this with logo at the top, blank, timePickr and button, and blank:

```
  .    .      logo logo   .      .
  .    .       .    .     .      .
  . timePick   .    .   buttonOK .
  .    .       .    .     .      .
```

But with the following code I don't have that.

```css
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 10vh 15vh 60vh 15vh;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
  ". . logo logo . ."
  ". . . . . ."
  ". timePick . . buttonOK ."
  ". . . . . .";
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold
}

.logo{
  grid-area: logo;
}

.timePick{
  grid-area: timePick;
}

.buttonOK{
  grid-area: buttonOK;
}

.imLogo{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
                <img class="imLogo" src="http://placehold.it/500x100" />
            </div>
            <div class="timePick">
                <h1> time </h1>
            </div>
            <div class= "buttonOK">
                <h1> button </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Do you know what is wrong with my CSS ?

---

### EDIT

With code snippet i have expected behavior. But in React, I have logo at the top and timePick and Button at the very bottom right. My code is exactly the same in React exept class -> className.

Do you know how to correct it ?

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Well, it is strange, using Snippet I have what I expect, but in React I don't

Comment: You probably need to add `'`'s around your grid-template-areas in React. I expect you want to read about adding a grid-template-area in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394549/how-to-modify-grid-template-areas-with-javascript

Comment: @RMo : no it doesn't change the behavior. (I suppose the simple quote ' is necessary outside CSS, not inside)

Comment: You may want to post your react code and the relevant ( css + html ) output, since the code you are providing works.